# SUMIFS Is Blank OR Other Condition

Tags: excel

I am trying to sum the values in the B2:B4 range using the SUMIFS function if the dates in the C2:C4 range are either blank or after the date in cell C1.

[image]

I can add the values in B if cells in C2:C4 are either blank or if the dates are after C1, in separate formulae, but I cannot seem to combine those conditions into one formula with an OR condition.

=SUMIFS(B2:B4,C2:C4,"") + SUMIFS(B2:B4,C2:C4,">"&C1)

The formula that I am working on is actually much longer and complicated so I want to combine these conditions into one formula or condition inside a SUMIFS if possible.

I have looked for hours but cannot seem to find what I am looking for. Solutions I have found thus far test for blank and a text value or if greater than 0, but not a comparison of non-text non-zero values such as dates. Does anyone know of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can not put the "or" condition in one criteria range with cell reference.
You can use the SUMIFS formula but you have to hard code the criteria value of date.
Pass the "or" conditions in { },this will return the value for both "or" conditions than use SUM function to get the total value.

SUM(SUMIFS(B2:B4,C2:C4,{">15-05-2021",""}))

Use of SUMPRODUCT function will be a better option in given condition

SUMPRODUCT(--(C2:C4>C1)+(C2:C4=""),B2:B4)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Hardcoding unfortunately does not work for my requirements, and I need to add more conditions in addition to greater than the date and not zero. They are too complicated to present here. That's why I would like to be able to build on the SUMIFS.

Answer (score 0):

A sum is already a OR operation so just do SUMIFS(...) + SUMIFS(...).